# Show that the equivalence classes of $R$ correspond to the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, equivalence-relations

Let $p$ and $q$ be any two distinct prime numbers and define the relation $aRb$ on integers $a,b$ by: $aRb$ iff $b−a$ is divisible by both $p$ and $q$. For this relation $R$:

(1) Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

(2) Show that the equivalence classes of $R$ correspond to the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$. That is: $[a]=[b]$ as equivalence classes of $R$ if and only if $[a]=[b]$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.

You may use the following lemma:

If $p$ is prime and $p∣mn$, then $p∣m$ or $p∣n$.

This question is also asked in another topic but it's still unanswered. For me, I proved the first part. But the second part I don't have any ideas. Does anyone know how to prove this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$?

Comment: $b-a \equiv 0$ (mod $pq$) because there must be some $pq$ that is equal to $b-a$.

Comment: It's important to start out with the correct definition of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$: $x\equiv 0$ (mod $n$) usually means that $n$ divides $x$.

Comment: I see that it's $a-b$ instead of $b-a$ what I assumed. I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot!

Edit: Actually both should be ok right? Since it's an equivalence relation.

Comment: Since equivalence relations are symmetric, the proof should work with $a-b$ or $b-a$, it does not matter which way you write it. If the answer solves your problem, consider accepting it :)

Comment: Yes your answer indeed solved my problem. Now I also noticed why it was necessary to prove the equivalance relation first.

Comment: Great! There should be a little check mark to accept the answer down below

Comment: I think that the definition wasn't that clear for me in the beginning. It's easy to get stuck when the definition isn't clear. In short, learned something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are trying to prove that $[a]=[b]$ if and only if $a\equiv b \; \text{(mod $pq$)}$. First assume that $[a]=[b]$. Then $a\in [b]$, so $aRb$. Therefore, $a-b$ is divisible by both $p$ and $q$. Since $p$ and $q$ are both prime, and since they are distinct, this implies that $a-b$ is divisible by $pq$ (this is a statement that you should prove as well, if you don't already know why it is true. It is important that $p$ and $q$ are both prime.) Thus $a\equiv b \; \text{(mod $pq$)}$.

For the converse, assume that $a\equiv b \; \text{(mod $pq$)}$. Then $a-b$ is divisible by $pq$. Thus, $p$ and $q$ both divide $a-b$ (this direction is a little easier to prove, and does not require both $p$ and $q$ to be prime. Still, you should make sure you are able to prove this statement by definition of what it means when one number "divides" another.) We conclude that $aRb$ and therefore $[a]=[b]$. (It is true in general that if $R$ is an equivalence relation, then $aRb$ means that $[a]=[b]$. Again, you should make sure you are able to prove this using the properties of equivalence relations and the definition of an equivalence class.)